# Import app phonegap including paypal plugin in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, cordova, paypal, phonegap-plugins

I've a problem with Eclipse, I import an app **Phonegap** with plugin **Paypal** installed , and using **paypal** plugin i get the following error.

> "PaymentActivity cannot be resolved to a variable",
>   "PaymentConfirmation cannot be resolved to a type"

[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/I48HQ.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ieq8n.png)

Answer (score 0):

is the variable getting declared inside a loop? Because probably this error occurs when the code is unable to retrieve the variable. for eg:

if you are declaring 'finalAmount' within the for loop. Once your for loop exits, 'finalAmount' goes out of scope. Meaning, program has no clue it ever existed.

Comment: i believe that is a problem con a file java , i don't know exactcly.

Comment: i Have not used a paypal plugin with cordova as of now but found few links[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27129882/android-activity-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-type) and [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13615964/the-import-org-apache-cordova-cannot-be-resolved) both of then points that the problem might be related to importing a SDK